# Where can I find site statistics, now that we have graduated?

Tags: support

Now that we have graduated, where can I find statistics such as number of questions per day, and the answer to question ratio?

Comment: Yeah, come and hangout in chat, and reminisce about the good old days when we were considered a trusted part of the community. ;) I lost pretty much all access when, but on the upside, I've recently been allowed to approve wiki-edits again. Yey!

Answer (score 5):

Now that the site has been graduated we're not really supposed to be concerned with these metrics, the idea being that the site has proven it's "healthy enough" to stand on its own (and frankly these stats are only part of the picture pre-graduation). [Site analytics](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) are available to users with 25,000 reputation or more.

For users with less reputation [Stack Exchange Data Explorer queries](http://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/478426/questions-per-day-on-stack-exchange) can give some of the same information, albeit in a less-friendly format.